# Why the call to Managed c++ class doesn't wait for it to finish?

Tags: c#, c++, command-line-interface, clr, managed

Lets say we have a situation like this:

//Idl file implementation

```
[
  object,
  uuid(44E43325-D296-4875-8473-88E1076BA98A),
  helpstring("INativeCpp Interface"),
  pointer_default(unique)
]

interface INativeCpp : IDispatch
{
   [id(1)] HRESULT ExecuteCommand([in] long CommandID);
}

library NativeCppLib
{
    importlib("stdole32.tlb");
    importlib("stdole2.tlb");

    [
       uuid(98D53837-D12A-439B-AA1B-2B838EEF30CF),
       helpstring("NativeCppClass")
    ]
    coclass NativeCpp
    {
       [default] interface INativeCpp;
    };
}
```

//Native C++

```
//I had to define this interface with the same method as INativeCpp com interface as I was having some access dilemma. So, i defined this interface at the common location which NativeCpp class and ManagedCpp class both can access.
class NativeCppInterface
{
 public:
    NativeCppInterface();
    virtual ~NativeCppInterface();
    virtual HRESULT ExecuteCommand(long CommandID) = 0;
}

enum enCommands
{
     Save = 1,
     Refresh = 2
}

class ATL_NO_VTABLE NativeCpp:
  public CComObjectRootEx<CComSingleThreadModel>,
  public CComCoClass<NativeCpp, &CLSID_NativeCpp>,
  public IDispatchImpl<INativeCpp, &IID_INativeCpp, &LIBID_NativeCppLib>,
  public NativeCppInterface
{
   STDMETHODIMP ExecuteCommand(long CommandID)   //Takes around 2 minutes.
   {
      switch (enCommands(CommandID))
      {
         case enCommands::Save:
           if (!!_pSaveHandler)
           {
              _pSaveHandler->OnExecute();  //Executes some sequential methods and then launches one window. And then proceeds.
           }
           break;
         case enCommands::Refresh:
            if (!!_pPropertiesHandler)
            {
                    GetObjectDeatilsList(4);    //Executes some sequential methods. Nothing special.
            }
            break;
         default:
            break;
       }
       return S_OK;
    }
}
```

//Managed C++ (compile with /clr option)

```
public ref class ManagedCpp : IWrapper
{
  NativeCppInterface* native;
  ManagedCpp(NativeCppInterface* ptr)
  {
    native = ptr
  }
  void ExecuteCommand(int64_t CommandID)
  {
     native->ExecuteCommand((long)CommandID);
  }
}
```

//C# Project

```
public interface IWrapper
{
  void ExecuteCommand(long CommandID);
}

public class MainClass
{
  IWrapper _wrapper;

  MainClass(IWrapper wrapper)
  {
    _wrapper = wrapper;
  }

  void DoOperation()
  {
    _wrapper.ExecuteCommand(1);
    int nextline = 5;
  }
}
```

Now, when i call `DoOperation()`, the call goes to `ExecuteCommand()` of NativeCpp but before `ExecuteCommand()` completes, the C# code execution goes to execute `int nextline = 5;`. It doesn't wait for the `ExecuteCommand()` to finish. Why is that? And what can I do so that it will wait?

Note: I have tried `using System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke()`. That does the trick. But, if the communication with ManagedCpp is frequent, then sometimes Dispatcher gets too many Invokes and it hangs. So, I wanted to know that why the call to ManagedCpp is launched asynchronously in the first place?

Also I want to launch some UI Window from `ExecuteCommand()` method, so I really want to call this method exactly on the thread C# code is running.

Comment: What does ExecuteCommand() function contains?

Comment: Without seeing what’s in ‘ExecuteCommand()’ it’s impossible to tell. From what you’ve shown, nothing is asynchronous

Comment: @WBuck I have updated the code. ExecuteCommand() executes only sequential methods. There is nothing special about it. Also, NativeCpp class is a com implemented class with the methods defined in idl file. I don't know if this information is important or not.

Comment: I am trying to call ExecuteCommand when an event subscriber method is called. So, that thread is MTA thread. May be that has something to do with why the method gets executed asynchronously!